# Formula to bucket the range of numbers

Tags: excel

I have over 10,000 lines of data, I would like to have the range starting from 50-10,000

For example

50-52

53-55

56-58 and etc.

Any Excel formulas to bucket the range of numbers so that I will save up the trouble typing a few thousand lines for the range?

Comment: I suggest to edit your question and specify what results you want to show. I mean "50-52" seems an odd output.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what you're wanting to do with that subset of values from your range, but you can perform functions on a subset of values by using an **array formula**

```
{=AVERAGE(IF((A1:A10>=2)*(A1:A10<=5),A1:A10))}
```

This example identifies all values in the range 2-5 from the range A1:A10, and executes AVERAGE just using those values rather than the entire A1:A10 dataset.

Answer (score 0):

From Excel help:

> Group or ungroup numeric items in a
>   PivotTable or PivotChart field You
>   cannot group items in PivotTable and
>   PivotChart reports that are based on
>   source data from OLAP databases.
>
> To group numeric items, do the
>   following:
>
> - Right-click the field that contains
>     the numeric items that you want to
>     group, point to Group and Outline on
>     the shortcut menu, and then click
>     Group.
> - If necessary, type the first item that
>     you want to group in the Starting at
>     box.
> - If necessary, type the last item that
>     you want to group in the Ending at
>     box.
> - In the By box, type the number of
>     items that you want in each group.
>
> **Notes**
>
> To ungroup numeric items   Right-click
>   the group, point to Group and Outline
>   on the shortcut menu, and then click
>   Ungroup. You cannot ungroup a single
>   group in a numeric field; Microsoft
>   Excel ungroups all groups for the
>   field.
>
> Effects on associated PivotChart
>   reports   When you group and ungroup
>   data in a PivotTable report that is
>   associated with a PivotChart report,
>   some PivotChart report formatting may
>   be lost.